# What is the difference between "Over the following years" and "In the following years"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A report of sentences that I found on Google follows:

**Over the following years**

> - Although William's main rivals were gone, he still faced rebellions **over the following years** and was not secure on his throne until after 1072
> - Support for gun control slipped to 54 percent **over the following years**.

**In the following years**

> - The 10-year difference between the youngest and oldest is not so dramatic here, but begins to register **in the following years**.
> - After the fall of Antwerp in 1585, King Philip II ordered Alexander Farnese to direct his military actions first towards the failed
>     campaign of the Spanish Armada, then against France to prevent the
>     succession of King Henry IV. **In the following years** the Army of
>     Flanders was entirely on the defensive.

Answer (score 1):

While both mean that *for a particular period*, something happened, ***'over'*** emphasizes more on gradual procedure, showing the change periodically. On the other hand, ***'in'*** talks about the results straightforwardly. The flair of *'through something'* lacks there.

Think of an example wherein you want to talk about someone's struggle before his success. Here, using `over the following years` fits better. Because using that phrase, you'd emphasize on the periodical events and efforts through which he turned from rags to riches. Nevertheless, you might use `in the following years` simply to show his success.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two points to lexico-aspectual (I pulled that bit of jargon out of my elbow) features of the verb-phrases when combined with prepositions like in|over.

Sporadic or gradual action that occurs periodically or progresses piecemeal (irregularly, but in a clear trend) throughout a time-**span**:

> he still *faced* rebellions *over* the following years
>
> Support for gun control *slipped to 54 percent over* the following years.

Incipient action that begins within a certain identifiable time-**frame**:

> The ... difference ... *begins to register in* the following years.

The predicate is confined to and obtains to a specific time-*frame*

> *In* the following years the Army of Flanders *was entirely on* the defensive.